# Show non-sibling/immediate div on hover

Tags: css

Im trying to show non-sibling/immediate div in 3 layers dropdown menu.

Browse Ads - Jobs - XZY

```
            <a href="#">Browse Ads</a>

                <div class="sub-nav-container"  >
                     <div class="layout-container">

                        <div  class="sub-navs">
                            <p class="sub-nav-title">Ads Category</p>
                            <a id="sub-nav-job" href> Jobs Available</a>

                            <a id="sub-nav-services" href>Services</a>
                        </div>

                        <div   class="sub-navs">
                            <p class="sub-nav-title">Favourites</p>

                            <div id="sub-nav-job-sub"  class="sub-nav-sub">
                                <a href>IT</a>
                                <a href>office</a>
                            </div>

                            <div id="sub-nav-real-estate-sub" class="sub-nav-sub">
                                <a href>Rent Apartment</a>
                                <a href>Buy House</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                     </div>
                </div>  

#site-navigation  .sub-navs  .sub-nav-sub {visibility:hidden}    
#site-navigation a#sub-nav-job:hover  > #sub-nav-job-sub {  visibility: visible}
```

But Im not getting the result.

TIA for the effort.

Comment: can you reproduce this in a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: This is not possible with just CSS ... You can't travel the DOM that way.

Comment: @Huangism 

Please check here. http://jsfiddle.net/yxh8W/

Comment: @r2c3 as Danko mentioned this is not possible with CSS with your current html structure. If you change the structure so that the sub menu is a child of the hovered menu then you can do it with css